# While creating file or renaming file with Umlaute characters, it is not saving properly

Tags: php

Just typing Umlaute characters while creating new file, it is propely saved. But while creting in other way it is not. I am trying in php.
i just tried in this way

```
 $a = 'ä';
    alert($a,1); 
    echo $a;
and 


 file_put_contents("D:/ätest.txt","Hello");
```

This displays some weird characters.
    So give me soution as fast as you can.

Comment: Does your filesystem use the appropriate charset?

Comment: And the easiest, fastest solution is to not use umlaut characters in your filenames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you probably need to specify that you want PHP to use UTF-8 (or whatever character set).

This website has a lot of good information on the subject of PHP + UTF-8: http://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

At least try setting `default_charset = "utf-8";` in your `php.ini` configuration file.

You could also try specifically encoding the data before writing to the file:

```
$fileName = utf8_encode("D:/ätest.txt");
$fileContent = utf8_encode("Hello");
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileContent);
```